# Linear extension of a functional on closed unit ball.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

> Let $X$ be a normed linear space with closed unit ball $B$. Suppose the function $f: B\rightarrow [-1,1]$ has the property that whenever $x,y,x+y$ and $\lambda x$ belong to $B$, $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(\lambda x)=\lambda f(x)$. Show that $f$ is the restriction to $B$ of a linear functional on all of $X$.

I was wondering how to prove this proposition? Hahn-Banach theorem does not seem to work.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can directly write down the (unique) extension. Any idea how $\tilde{f}(x)$ could be defined for $\lVert x\rVert > 1$?

Comment: Hi, Daniel. I tried to write down some extension like $g(x)=f(x)/||x||$, but it's not linear. This is a part of the proof of Alaoglu's theorem. I'm confused...

Comment: You need in particular the homogeneity, you need $g(\lambda x) = \lambda g(x)$ for all $x$ and $\lambda$. If $\lVert x\rVert \leqslant 1$, you have $g(x) = f(x)$. What should $g(x)$ be if $\lVert x\rVert = c > 1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every linear map $g$ satisfies $g(x) = t\cdot g(t^{-1}\cdot x)$ for all $x$ and all scalars $t\neq 0$. Picking $t$ (for a given $x$) in such a way that $t^{-1}x \in B$, we can replace $g$ with $f$ on the right, and see that

$$g(x) := (1 + \lVert x\rVert)\cdot f\biggl(\frac{1}{1+\lVert x\rVert}\cdot x\biggr)$$

is the only candidate for a linear extension of $f$ to all of $X$. (Here I chose $t(x) = 1+\lVert x\rVert$, of course other choices can be made, they all lead to the same function.)

I leave it to you to verify that $g$ is indeed an extension of $f$, and that $g$ is in fact linear.